# ng-forward bootstrap function and/or babel transpilation not working on stock android browser

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When I view my app on my stock Android browser all I see is a white screen. I've seen a few issues about the "white screen of death" in Ionic apps, but none of that seems to apply here. It's difficult to debug, since I don't know of any way to see JS errors on a mobile browser (other than Chrome and its remote debugging feature). I guess my hope is that there's something obviously wrong with my bootstrap function, my main application class or my router. I'm using Angular 1.5.0-rc.2 and ng-forward. Here's the relevant part of my `index.html`:

```
<!-- no Angular components are loaded in here on stock Android browser -->
<myapp>
    loading . . .
</myapp>

<script src="/path/to/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { bootstrap } from 'ng-forward';
import { Application } from '../components/app/Application';
import config from './config/app.config';

bootstrap(Application, [
    'ui.router',
    config.name
]);
```

**app.config.js**

```
export default angular.module('app.config', [])
.config(['$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', Config]);

function Config($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $animateProvider, $httpProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
```

**Routes.js**

```
import { Home } from '../../components/home/Home';

class Routes
{
    static Config()
    {
        return [
            {
                url: '/',
                name: 'home',
                component: Home,
                template: '<home></home>'
            }
        ]
    }
}
export default Routes.Config()
```

**Application.js**

```
import { Component, StateConfig, Inject } from 'ng-forward';
import Routes from '../../app/config/Routes';

@Component({
    selector: 'myapp',
    template: `
        <h1>My App</h1>
        <ng-outlet></ng-outlet>
    `
})
@StateConfig(Routes)
export class Application
{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log('Application component instantiated');
    }
}
```

This works on every desktop browser I've tried, and also on mobile using Chrome, Safari and Firefox. On my stock Android browser, the `<myapp></myapp>` and `<home></home>` components are never populated.

**update**

It occurs to me that this might instead/also be a Babel transpilation issue. I've got 4 Angular apps, 1 works on stock android browser, 3 don't. The only unique difference between the one that works and the three that don't is those three are es6. So I thought I'd include my Babel setup here, too, in case that helps with diagnosis:

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.3.19"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.3.13",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0"
},
"babel": {
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "stage-0",
        "stage-3"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-runtime",
        "transform-regenerator",
        "syntax-async-functions",
        "transform-async-to-generator",
        "transform-decorators-legacy"
    ]
}
```

**babel.js (grunt)**

```
module.exports = function(grunt)
{
    grunt.config.set('babel', {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'stage-3'],
            plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy']
        },
        client: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= grunt.path.client %>',
                src: ['{app,components,services}/**/*.js'],
                dest: '<%= grunt.path.tmp %>'
            }]
        }
    });
};
```

**Update**

I found about about Android's `about:debug` setting for the stock browser. You type that into the address bar and hit enter, and then you suddenly have a `Debug` setting in the browser settings, among which is a checkbox for "Show JavaScript Console". However, toggling that produces no effect whatsoever (even when I know there are JS errors). HTC was no help there. Still flummoxed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the transpiled code in a `try/catch` and got the error, `ReferenceError: Set is not defined`, which led me to the `reflect-metatdata` function, which was trying to create a polyfill. The solution appears to be simply importing `babel-polyfill` in my bootstrap file:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';

// Missing this appears to be the cause of the problem
import 'babel-polyfill';

import { bootstrap } from 'ng-forward';
import { Application } from '../components/app/Application';
import config from './config/app.config';

bootstrap(Application, [
    'ui.router',
    config.name
]);
```

Comment: Right, Babel only transpiles syntax so you need something to polyfill everything else. I added some docs on this and linked to the polyfill page http://babeljs.io/#polyfill. If you are using a library, you'll probably want the transform-runtime plugin.